# SQL TRUNC Minutes from Sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp, sysdate

I am currently using one of the columns to extract every minute of the time, however, it would skip some minutes because no data was inserted that minute.

**Output Below Expected.**

```
12-19-2017 02:23:00
12-19-2017 02:24:00
12-19-2017 02:25:00
12-19-2017 02:26:00
12-19-2017 02:27:00
12-19-2017 02:28:00
12-19-2017 02:29:00
12-19-2017 02:30:00
12-19-2017 02:31:00
12-19-2017 02:32:00
12-19-2017 02:33:00
12-19-2017 02:34:00
```

**What I am getting.**(Current time is 13:11

```
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
12-19-2017 13:11:00
```

**Query**

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MI')  AS TIME_STAMP From Table where SYSDATE >= sysdate - 1;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That query is product specific.

Comment: @jarlh Oracle RDBMS

Comment: So what do you want? List of dates and times with one-minute step, even if some minutes are not present in the table, right?

Comment: `From Table`? What table? Do **YOU** understand your own question?

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, exactly that. some minutes are not present that's why I want to extract all the minutes like you said one-minute step using Sysdate.

Comment: See the answer of Alex Poole then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if my starting time was from Yesterday midnight to now then I want to see output of each minute.

If you want to generate a range of values based on sysdate then you use a hierarchical query against the `dual` table, rather than having to refer to a real table:

```
select trunc(sysdate - 1) + (level - 1)/1440 as result
from dual
connect by level <= (sysdate - trunc(sysdate - 1))*1440
order by result;

RESULT
-------------------
2017-12-18 00:00:00
2017-12-18 00:01:00
2017-12-18 00:02:00
2017-12-18 00:03:00
...
2017-12-18 23:57:00
2017-12-18 23:58:00
2017-12-18 23:59:00
2017-12-19 00:00:00
2017-12-19 00:01:00
2017-12-19 00:02:00
2017-12-19 00:03:00
...
2017-12-19 14:21:00
2017-12-19 14:22:00
2017-12-19 14:23:00
```

This uses `trunc(sysdate - 1)` to get midnight yesterday as the starting point; calculates the number of minutes between then and now as `(sysdate - trunc(sysdate - 1))*1440)`; and uses the connect-by syntax to add one minute to the start time until it reaches that limit.

(It’s up to, but not including, the current minute. If you want that as well, just add 1 to the end of the terminating condition.)

Depending on what you really want to end up with, you could use that as a CTE or inline view to generate all of those minutes, and then left-join to your real table to find matching data if it exists.

---

If you want a user to supply the start and end time you can pass those as variables, something like:

```
select trunc(:start_time, 'MI') + (level - 1)/1440 as result
from dual
connect by level <= (:end_time - :start_time)*1440
order by result;
```

where `:start_time` and `:end_time` here are bind variables that you populate with the start and end time. The exact mechanism depends on how the values will get from the user to the query; in SQL*Plus or a SQL Developer worksheet you'd need to get them as strings and add (explicit) conversion of those strings to dates. From a Java application say you can bind date datatypes directly.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for you are awesome. Thank you

Comment: One question, I am OK using the from Dual. How can I add a where clause for user to pick the start and end time for the RESULT?

Comment: @user206168 - I've added a brief idea of how to do that. If it isn't clear then you should ask a new question, including how the data is entered by the user and what data type it is by the time it reaches the query.

Comment: Alex, can you plz help. I am getting an error for user-entered date and time. My query is like `select trunc(to_char('03-12-2018 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - 3) + (level - 1)/1440 as CLOCK` and  error is at the left join I did on different able. `where startdatetime >= TO_DATE('03-12-2018 00:00:00','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') group by trunc(restoredatetime,'MI')` says `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

Comment: You need to ask a new question, with all the details.  But you seem to be using `to_char()` instead of `to_date()`?

Answer (score 2):

problem is : you're always selecting the same time (sysdate) from your table for all rows of today by

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate,'mi')  as time_stamp
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE sysdate >= sysdate - 1;
```

try to rewrite the query as :

```
SELECT to_char(date1,'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mi:ss')  as time_stamp
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE sysdate >= sysdate - 1; 
-- assuming you have a date column named DATE1 in your table, and populated every minute.
```

(comparing hour `02` and `13`, i decided to format with `hh` instead of `hh24`)

Comment: I am sorry, I should've mentioned that 24 HR clock doesn't matter. what I am not able to extract is every minute from `SYSDATE`. Example if my starting time was from Yesterday midnight to now then I want to see output of each minute.

Comment: @user206168 i think you have a table and one of the date column of that is populated, wasn't that? Could you share your tables structure?